# My view cutting from top and bottom due Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, ios8.1

I make my project in Xcode 6.1 with adoptive layout. i run it on iOS 8 it run fine but when run iOs 7.1 then my view cut from top and bottom and status bar shift down as you can see in Image.

Link- [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zslgp1f52my1ui/photo.PNG?dl=0).

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Set your launch image, then you will be fine.

Comment: set Default-568@2x.png image in your project.